# How to automatically split a table in a SSIS package

Tags: sql, ssis, split, package

part of a longer SSIS task is to read in 10 Mio. rows of data into a table "trunk" and sort this by two different ids in order to join another column.

It turned out that sorting 10 Mio. rows is too much for our server adn thus I need a solution that automatically splits the 10 Mio. rows in table "trunk" into multiple parts.

Currently I did this manually by selecting the TOP 5 Mio via an SQL statement executing the package and then selecting the BOTTOM 5 Mio.

Is there any way to do this either automatically or completely different?

Comment: Where are you doing your sorting. If you are using the SSIS sort task option then this may very well cause memory pressure as it is a full in memory operation, rather insert directly into SQL and handle sorting there.

Comment: How big is the related table? you may consider lookup instead of join.

Comment: The related table contains around 10 k rows and growing. How would I do a lookup in SSIS? I thought "lookup" as VLOOKUP in Excel is the same as a JOIN in SSIS resp. SQL

Comment: 10k rows and only one column can be cached without issues. I would use lookup: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx

Comment: Can you clarify "table trunk and sort this by two different ids in order to join another column." are you pre sorting the data so you can  join it in a SSIS package? What are you doing exactly? which parts are in the database and which are in SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

While reading your data from source to the destination table (trunk), you can split it.
You Row Counter between the source and destination. If row count > 5 M, divert to data flow to the next table. You can even create the table dynamically.

Comment: Great idea, but how do I do this: "If row count > 5 M, divert to data flow to the next table. You can even create the table dynamically." Currently, I have to identical data flow tasks with the only difference being in SQL statement to retrieve data from trunk. First it is ROW 1 to 5 M and in the other it is ROW 5 M + 1 to 10 M.

Comment: This won't work. Row counter only updates the variable after the last row passed through.

Comment: Why wont this work? I tested it and I get results which make sense. How would I notice that something is missing? Do you mean that I cannot precisely reference the individual rows via Row counter? Let's say I have 10 rows. First, I import the first 5 rows via SELECT * FROM WHERE row_counter = 1 To 5 and then  the next 5 with 6 To 10. Is it possible not all 10 rows are imported via that way and that e.g. I have duplicates although the total number is still 10?